# Background color of VS Package Addin?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-addins

this may be a pretty simple question.

I've created a VS Package and it has a nice little GUI. The background of the GUI should be System.Colors.ControlBrush:

```
<Grid Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}">
```

Now I have the problem, that it changes the color of the Grid, but not of the rest of the window. -> [Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/974862/Office/white.JPG)

I thought I could change the background of the UserControl the same way, but somehow it doesn't work. Now it doesn't really look that great, if a part of the window is grey and the rest is white.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UserControl is probably not covering the entire window.

Remove any `Width` or `Height` attributes and make sure that the Horizontal/Vertical Alignments are both `Stretch`.

Comment: hmmm... that solves the color problem. Guess now I have to fight with the design again to make it look like it should, as this moves everything somewhere else.

Comment: @Feroc: Put your controls in a separate non-`Stretch` panel.

Comment: thx, I will give this a try, but only if I have to change something on the design again. At the moment everything is in place and I don't want to touch it again. :D